# can we make multiple foreign keys of different table link with a same primary key?

Tags: sql-server

i have created one parent table , user details.

now i wanted to have 8 child table ?

is it possible that U_id column (PK) in userdetail table can act as foreign key for those 8 child table ?

It means > Can one primary key be used as foreign key for 8 different table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, yes. You can have as many foreign keys as you want referencing the same primary key.

Comment: The recommended limit for the number of foreign keys in a table is 253. See Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server on MSDN.

Microsoft says:

"Although a table can contain an unlimited number of FOREIGN KEY constraints, the recommended maximum is 253. Depending on the hardware configuration hosting SQL Server, specifying additional FOREIGN KEY constraints may be expensive for the query optimizer to process."